# ng-class not firing inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I have tried different solutions i have seen around but i can't seem to make my ng-class work.

none of them are getting the class, but if i add them manually it works.
my console.log never fires so am i using the ng-class in a wring way ?

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let master of masters; let i = index">
                    <div  class="m-portlet m-portlet--collapsed  m-portlet--head-solid-bg m-portlet--head-sm" ng-class="getMasterTypeClass(master.masterID)" data-portlet="true" id="m_portlet_tools_{{master.masterID}}">
```

**TS**

```
getMasterTypeClass(masterID){

        var returnClass = "";
        if (masterID > 2999 && masterID < 4000) {
            returnClass = "m-portlet--success";
        } else if (masterID > 3999 && masterID < 5000) {
            returnClass = "m-portlet--primary";
        } else if (masterID > 4999 && masterID < 6000) {
            returnClass = "m-portlet--warning";
        } else if (masterID > 100000) {
            returnClass = 'primary';
        } else {
            returnClass = 'primary';
        }
        console.log(returnClass);
        return returnClass;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, use it like this:

```
[ngClass]="getMasterTypeClass(master.masterID)"
```

Comment: Some explanation would be good, since he doesn't know how to use it.

Comment: ofc. it worked as soon as i saw your fix. how could i miss it. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't really need `[ngModule]` since you're returning just a simple string (unless you want to toggle the class). You can directly bind it to `[class]="getMasterTypeClass(master.masterID)"`. [Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uj46rw).

And you can also skip the temporary `returnClass` variable inside the `getMasterTypeClass` and return directly in each `if`/`if else` (also shown in the example).

Edit: Sorry, you do actually need `[ngModule]` because you have other classes on the same element.